# Problem with handling the result of SELECT query in MYSQL C API

Tags: mysql, c, mariadb, mysql-connector-c

I'm getting a Internal Server Error with one of my scripts. I'm using MYSQL C API. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api.html

Here is the corresponding part of my script:

```
MYSQL *con;
MYSQL_RES *result;
MYSQL_ROW robe;

con = mysql_init(NULL);
if (!mysql_real_connect(valid values)) {
printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
printf("Could not connect\n");
exit(0); }

char somequery[512];
//userinput is sanitized beforehand
int sog = sprintf(somequery, "SELECT password from testtab WHERE username='%s'", userinput);

if (sog < 0) {
printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
printf("Something went wrong with Sprintf\n");
exit(0); }

int bos = mysql_real_query(con, somequery, strlen(somequery));
if (bos != 0) {
printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
printf("The query produced no result\n");
exit(0); }

result = mysql_store_result(con);
if (result == NULL) {
printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
printf("No Result Set Produced\n");
exit(0); }

robe = mysql_fetch_row(result);
char *passdb = robe[0];
printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
printf("And it is: %s", passdb);
```

A HTML form submits via POST to this script (part of which is seen above). When I submit a username which exists in the database beforehand, I'm receiving no error. Everything works fine.

The problem arises, when I'm submitting a username that doesn't exist in the said table(testtab). Well, I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error. I have looked at Apache Error log as well: "End of Script output before Headers".

I have tried a few things so far, but none of them worked. Any help is appreciated.

Note: Doing mysql_num_fields(result); in both cases gives 1.

Comment: You're not showing the entire program or entire output set, but I would bet there's something beyond what you're showing here that gets executed when the query succeeds that isn't being executed when the query fails. Hence my concern about the use of `exit(0)` on every failure.

Comment: Basically, you need something like a finalize step, that always executes, even when there's failures. Admittedly just a guess, I never hook web servers to databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution elsewhere, thanks to the help of some good people. It seems, that I had made a silly mistake as well as needed a thorough understanding of the difference between two MYSQL C API functions.

I'm writing the answer here, in hope of it benefiting others.

The mistakes is here:

```
 robe = mysql_fetch_row(result);
```

Though it is correct in itself. I fail to check its result. What happens is that when the SQL query is performed using a username that did not exist in the DB beforehand, the result is a empty set (and not a error).

The mysql_store_result and mysql_fetch_row have a slight difference here. While the former will not return NULL if the set is empty, the later will.

All I have to do is add a check after the above line with the logic:

```
if (robe == NULL) { 
//error occured 
} else { //go on 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should NEVER store passwords in a database, especially one that is reachable through an online service. `exit(0)` indicates success. It's also short-circuiting your output before it is completed. You can't just call exit(0) in the middle of producing output. Use some kind of "data not available" string instead.

Comment: 1. Where do you suggest to store passwords if not in a DB (though this point is irrelevant to the problem I'm facing) 2. Which 'exit(0)' are you talking about? None of them are cutting the script in the middle. Remember, I'm having issues only when I enter a wrong username (one that doesn't exist in the DB).

Comment: Does your database produce passwords for non-existent users? You exit when a query fails. Store a crypto hash of the users passwords.

Comment: 1. bro, you didn't answer my question. Where else do you suggest to store passwords if not in a DB (in a encrypted state)? Currently I do that. 2. I'm not sure what you mean to ask by "produce password for non-existent users". I have a sample database, with some sample data in it (manually inserted). A password corresponding to a unique username. 3. I totally have no idea what you mean by phrase "You exit when a query fails". Please rephrase as needed.

Comment: I did answer your question. Don't ever do it. Store a cryptographic hash of the password instead.

Comment: Never mind. I've had family over all evening and can't focus on this.

Comment: yes, you haven't focused as you have not read in the last comment that I'm actually using a cryptographic hash, even before you said so. Please have a look later on or tomorrow if you have time. Thank you. Please remember, my question here is about a different problem, and not about storing data.