# Why getting random outputs, in place of input taken in C?

Tags: c, arrays

This is C. So trying to put multiple inputs into this array and keep getting numbers like this for when output the input 6356740 "6356744 6356748 6356752"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int quiz[4];

    printf("Enter four quiz grades: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &quiz[1], &quiz[2], &quiz[3], &quiz[4]);

    printf("%d %d %d %d", &quiz[1], &quiz[2], &quiz[3], &quiz[4]);

}
```

Comment: How can someone tell why this is happening without knowing how you provided this input. As you have used `"8923498"`, this made it string and assigning it to integer is not a smart thing to do.

Comment: It doesnt matter what it was I was just putting like 1 2 3 4 and still getting those numbers

Comment: So do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I did not know that I did. Sorry, I'm new to the website

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d %d %d %d", &quiz[1], &quiz[2], &quiz[3], &quiz[4]);`   The `quiz[]` only has 4 'slots' and in C, indexing into arrays starts at 0 and continues to (number of entries in array -1)

Answer (score 2):

An array with K elements is indexed from 0 to K-1.
(This is mentioned in any introduction to arrays.)
Reading or writing `quiz[4]` has undefined behaviour.

You should not pass pointers to `printf` if you want to print integers.

```
int main()
{
    int quiz[4];

    printf("Enter four quiz grades: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &quiz[0], &quiz[1], &quiz[2], &quiz[3]);

    printf("%d %d %d %d", quiz[0], quiz[1], quiz[2], quiz[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined your array as

`int quiz[4]` which means the first reference is `quiz[0]`, the second is `quiz[1]`, the third is `quiz[2]` and the last is `quiz[3]`.

In your code you are referencing the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and **undefined** 5th entry.  This is important as you may be corrupting the data in your program which can caused undefined results.

The numbers you are seeing are the integer values of the addresses pointing to the ints in your array.  Notice they increase by 4 which is the size of an int.

Also, your printf is printing the addresses of the int and not the ints themselves.  The line should read

`printf(“%d %d %d %d”, quiz[0], quiz[1], quiz[2], quiz[3]);`

Comment: Pointers and arrays are confusing at first but they will come naturally.  Upvote if this was useful.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If the grades being input are numbers, that '%d' in all four places is okay. But if you are entering alphabets, than you should be using '%s' instead.

And as Hogstrom and molbdnilo said, the first entry of a Array is 0, than second is 1, and so on. Hence you have to use &quiz[0] than &quiz[1] .. and so on.

Comment: There'd be more work to do than just changing `%d` to `%s` if entering strings.  It also isn't clear that the user is thinking of entering strings.  Your second paragraph more or less covers one of the issues; it doesn't cover the other big problem.

Comment: yes, I agree with that. But given the word 'quiz' here, I think it is just a school project without the security considerations. Usually grades are given as alphabets, thus I provided the basic answer to that. btw, can you look at my recent question for my own situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797828/problem-with-handling-the-result-of-select-query-in-mysql-c-api